# nested for loop multiplication table python

Tags: python, multiplication

Have an assignment for python class, we have to make a program that asks for an input and will display a multiplication table for all values up to the input. It requires we use a nested for loop.

```
def mathTable(column, tuple):
    for column in range(1, 13):
        for tuple in range(1, 13):
            print("%6d" % (column * tuple), end = '')
    print("")

x = int(input("Enter the value of the multiplication table: "))
column = ""
tuple = ''
print(mathTable(column, tuple))
```

this is what it needs to look like:

[image]

Comment: Fine. Do you have a question?

Comment: sorry, wanted to know how to make the output dependent on the input, right now the code executes and gives me a constant wall of numbers that are the same (all the multiplication tables of 1-12) I am very new to programming and am not sure what I am doing wrong at the moment. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing variable and parameter names. That is, when you create the for loops, you should be using new variables to loop over so you don't overwrite your parameters, column and tuple. I'd also change tuple to row to be more clear. your loop variables could be named c and r to keep things short.

Additionally, you hardcoded 13 as your table size. You should make sure to loop from 1 to the number of columns and 1 to the number of rows.

```
def mathTable(column, row):
  for r in range(1, row): #r is a temporary variable for the outer loop
    for c in range(1, column): #c is a temporary variable for the inner loop
      print("%6d" % (c * r), end = '') #note column and row don't change now, they just act as bounds for the loop
    print("")
```

now, if you call mathTable(3, 4), you'd get a multiplication table of

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
```

Comment: You should also mention passing the value(s) from `input` into the function and fixing the loop boundaries.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you're getting at?

Answer (score 0):

alright so after bashing my forehead on the numpad for a few hours I have realized I am a numbskull.

```
def mathTable(column, tuple):
    for c in range(1, x + 1):
        print("")
        for t in range(1, 13):
            print("%6d" % (c * t), end = '\t')
    return("\n")

x = int(input("Enter the value of the multiplication table: "))
column = ""
tuple = ''
print(mathTable(column, tuple))
```

so this is what ended up working perfectly, I used the first for statement to define how many rows I was asking for and then the second for statement was the amount of times I would be multiplying the two together.
the second argument in the range of the first for statement is directly tied to my inputs and this allows me to vary the output of the table to any size I want (pls don't put 9 figure numbers in it, never put a sentinel value in so you'd have to close down your command line to do anything with it)

finally to get rid of the "NONE" text that appears after the table prints you need to keep in mind that you have created a function that doesn't actually answer anything so just saying {return("")} suited my purposes since I have achieved the output I set out to create.

Thank you to the person who tried to help me I am so sorry I didn't understand you at the time!

Answer (score -1):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, this is trivial with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def return_table(n):
    return np.arange(1, 13) * np.arange(1, n+1)[:, None]

print(return_table(3))

# [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
#  [ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24]
#  [ 3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36]]
```